# PHP script images are missing after migration and changing directory

Tags: php, directory, migration

I have installed my PHP script in a directory of my website psc.af/photo after migration to another domain and in its main directory (public_html in cPanel) everything works fine but the images are not showing up. When i inspect the image link it shows mynewdomain.com/photo/images which is not and it got the photo directory from my previous installation in sub directory. So i cant see the images.
I have tried to change my app url and its fine, the only issue is missing images.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:cDd2jFWmOeQajBVf+UbCcCW9v0OxeZC/w+mp8qwgw0g=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://psc.af/
```

This is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    Options -Indexes

    <Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </Files>

    <Files composer.json>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </Files>

    <Files composer.lock>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
        </Files>

    <Files .env>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </Files>

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Remove index.php
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: You need to show us all relevant code. We have no clue how you're setting the paths to the images. It's also unclear what the new URL is. Have you moved it from a sub folder on an old domain to the root of a new domain?

Comment: I have added .htaccess file to my question, and i am using .env file for the app url and new url is engindaily.com

Comment: I'm sorry, but that neither answered my question or made things clearer. Without knowing the old and the new URL's for the application or how you set the paths to the images, we won't have a clue what's going on.

Comment: Old url http://psc.af/photo/ and new url http://engindaily.com

Comment: Third time's a charm: _"or how you set the paths to the images"_. When we ask questions, it's so we can understand your issue better and be able to help. If you ignore some of the questions, we won't be able to help.

Comment: The issue is that i am using a script which i purchased and i dont have any idea about the paths, can i give you access cPanal to look it up?

Comment: It's pretty hard for us to help you fix some issue in an unknown script that we know nothing about. I would recommend that you contact the people you bought it from. A suggestion for future questions, add all information like that to the question from the start.